# What font is used for the title on the cover of Cryptonomicon?

Tags: font-identification

I'd like to find the font that was used on the cover of this edition of the book. Any ideas? I know other editions use other fonts.

[image: Cryptonomicon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is [**Newtext Std Demi**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/newtext/std-demi/):

[image]

[image]
[image]